# How to change existing python script for Postgres Dump?

Tags: python, database, postgresql

I have a python script that must create pg_dump file by Postgres DB, but here's the issue: this script don't work for me..
DB is on EC2 instance. Lambda have connection to EC2, VPC set correctly.

```
def dump():
    ssm = boto3.client('ssm', region_name='us-west-1')
    pg_host = get_parameters(ssm, "pg_host")
    pg_password = get_parameters(ssm, "pg_password")
    pg_database_name = get_parameters(ssm, "pg_database_name")
    pg_user = get_parameters(ssm, "pg_user")
    con = None
    try:

        # connect to the PostgreSQL server
        print('Connecting to the PostgreSQL database...')
        con = psycopg2.connect(
            host=pg_host,
            database=pg_database_name,
            user=pg_user,
            password=pg_password,
            port="5432")
            
        subprocess.call(['pg_dump', '-h', pg_host, '-U', pg_user, '-W', pg_password, '-p', '5432','-F', 't', '-f', '/tmp/pg_dump.sql', '-d', pg_database_name])
  
    finally:
        if con is not None:
            con.close()
            print('Done')
```

issue:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pg_dump'",
  "errorType": "FileNotFoundError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 50, in upload\n    dump()\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 42, in dump\n    subprocess.call(['pg_dump', '-h', pg_host, '-U', pg_user, '-W', pg_password, '-p', '5432','-F', 't', '-f', '/tmp/pg_dump.sql', '-d', pg_database_name])\n",
```

Comment: 1) You are not currently creating `pg_dump` file, you are just reading out the data from a table to a file. 2) If you want an actual complete `pg_dump` of a database you will need to use the `pg_dump` command in the Python script. Probably using `subprocess.call(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["pg_dump", "-d", "test", "-U", "postgres", "-f", "test.sql"])
```

Which produces:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 aklaver users 150M Aug 24 09:00 test.sql

head test.sql 

--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 14.5
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 14.5

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
```

Comment: Hello Adrian
Thank you for your answer.
Now I'm having an issue with dump file:
`Response

{
  "errorMessage": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pg_dump'",

  "errorType": "FileNotFoundError",

  "stackTrace": [

    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 50, in upload\n    dump()\n",

    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 42, in dump\n    subprocess.call([\"pg_dump\", \"-d\", pg_database_name, \"-U\", pg_user, \"-f\", \"/pg_dump.sql\"])\n",`

Comment: Could you please check if I made the correct changes?

Comment: I'm going to say it is due to `'-W', pg_password`. From here [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html): 'Force pg_dump to prompt for a password before connecting to a database.'.  You need to use [.pgpass](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html) or an [env variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html) to supply the password not `-W`. Test the command on the command line first before using it in Python.

Comment: It's still thinks that 'pg_dump' is a file and returns me "no such file or directory"..

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I used your code minus the `-W` and with my settings for the variables and it ran. What version of Python are you using and where are you running the code? Do you have `pg_dump` installed on the machine you are running this? Try running the command on the command line outside Python e.g `pg_dump -h <host> -d <db> -U <user> -p <port> -f /tmp/pg_dump.sql`

Comment: I have imported the postgre library into python and added this layer to AWS Lambda before. It should work.
On my machine the command works.

Everything works on my machine, but not in AWS Lambda.

Comment: well, looks like there's no correct lib with pg_dump in Lambda.
Do you know any lib for python3.8 that have pg_dump? Thanks in advance

Comment: `pg_dump` is a Postgres client program that is installed with Postgres. There is no Python lib that supplies it. To your question add more information about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: So I have an AWS Lambda function with Python3.8/3.9 runtime. In Lambda I have a Python script that needs to connect to an EC2 instance where Postgres is installed. The script then creates a pg_dump file and uploads it to the S3 Bucket. Before I had a script that takes data (you know, takes like hands) and writes it to the file. This is not what was expected and pg_restore can't be done from this file. I wanted to create a regular pg_dump file. All this is complicated by the fact that we cannot use a docker container for this.

Comment: Per previous instructions add the information above to your question. In meantime: 1) Think about setting up a `cron` job  on the EC2 instance that  uses `pg_dump` to create a dump file that you can move. 2) Figure out how to remotely access the EC2 instance from lambda and run `pg_dump` remotely.

Comment: Hello!
Just forgot to let you know, that I have found the solution for this issue, including your part of code. I just add pgdump bin as layer to Lambda.